# Spring.Web.Mvc5 2.0.1 won't work with System.Web.Mvc 5.2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, .net-assembly, spring.net

I've been updating packages in an .NET MVC 5 application that uses Spring.NET, and I'm trying to get Spring.Web.Mvc5 version with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3. I getting the following in the Fusion Log. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.OData 1.7, which seems to be dependent on a version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core that's later than 5.0.0.0; whenever I downgrade to 5.0.0.0, I lose the definition of `System.Web.Http.SingleResult`.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/24/2015 @ 2:44:55 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/SVN/Path-To/WebApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\SVN\Path-To\WebApp\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webapp\309524fe
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webapp\309524fe
LOG: AppName = da54b19b
Calling assembly : Spring.Web.Mvc5, Version=2.0.1.45000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\SVN\Path-To\WebApp\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webapp/309524fe/da54b19b/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webapp/309524fe/da54b19b/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SVN/Path-To/WebApp/bin/System.Web.Http.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\SVN\Path-To\WebApp\bin\System.Web.Http.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is that NuGet lost track of the version numbers it had installed and was no longer updating the `assemblyBinding` portion of `Web.config`. I'd never had any problems before now, and I kept playing whack-a-mole trying to figure out what the problem was. For what it's worth, here's the part of my configuration file that works, but yours will probably be different depending on the libraries you're using.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging.Core" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```